# can't write/read data from Firebase Realtime Database from Android App

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i did everything correctly i guess
i made sure that my app is connected to the firebase console
i changed the rules "write/read" to truth in firebase Realtime , still yet nothin happens when i try to write/data from my app

```
DatabaseReference usser ;
FirebaseDatabase database ;
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
usser = database.getReference().child("info");

       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                         
                incData();
            }
        });                   }

private void incData() {
    String username = user.getText().toString() ;
    String  password = pass.getText().toString() ;
   
    personData person1 = new personData(username , password) ;
    usser.push().setValue(person1) ;    }
```

this is my code i guess , anything wrong ?

Comment: Is anything relevant written to the logcat output of your app when the `setValue` call executes?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `setValue()` operation, to see if something goes wrong?